# .bachrc $PATH doesn't find my python scripts

Tags: python, scripts, bashrc

I've tried adding a path to my `.bashrc` file as follows

```
export PATH=/beda/users/home/user252083/bin:$PATH
```

and yes, I can then run the binary "bader", which is in the bin folder from anywhere. I also want to run python scripts added to the bin folder, e.g. I want to run `python charge.py` from any directory but I get the error message

```
python: can't open file 'charge.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

In order to start the script from `$PATH` -- You shouldn't start python scripts as

```
python scripy.py
```

This way You'll only run scripts in current directory. Instead start the script with a hashbang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

make it executable

```
chmod +x script.py
```

put it somewhere in your `$PATH` and then You'll be able to run it from Your shell.

```
script.py
```

If You'd also like to call it from other programs, such as krusader or what ever -- You'd need to add it to a login shell `$PATH` -- that is for example to add it's path to `~/.bash_login` or `~/.profile`.

---

By the way in windows python scripts are started as

```
python script.py
```

because windows shell (`command`) doesn't support hashbangs.

---

The reason to use

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

instead of

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

is that with the first approach You can control which python to run -- if Your site has multiple pythons installed. `env` will run the first python in Your `$PATH`. You can get a list of all executables `python` in Your site with

```
 which -a python
```